# Given a graph representing a NPSEM-IE, how can I show that another graph also represents one?

Tags: nonparametric, biostatistics, graph-theory, causal-diagram

Good morning,

I am currently following a class on Biostatistics and am currently struggling on an exercise. I am given 2 graphs $G1$ and $G2$.

Then, assuming that $G1$ represents a NPSEM-IE, I have to either show that $G2$ also represents a NPSEM-IE or give a counter-example.

First of all I am not sure about the model assumptions implied by saying that $G1$ represents a NPSEM-IE. Because then I think I would need to show that the model assumptions for $G2$ are satisfied under $G1$?

Thank you in advance for any clarification you could give.

Comment: By "NPSEM-IE", are you referring to a non-parametric structural equation model with independent error terms?